# Files from ajax.googleapis.com not loading

Tags: browser

I have been running into problems with files from http://ajax.googleapis.com loading, specifically, the file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js is not loading which happens to break a number of sites including Stack Overflow. This problem occurs in both Firefox 3.5.4 and Internet Explorer 6 inside of a corporate network, are there any ideas in regards to to get around this problem?

Comment: It does load for me. Maybe you had a problem loading this once and the cached version of your browser is not working. Try clearing your cache / an alternative browser.

Comment: Luka, as noted in the question, domain of the issue is inside of a corporate network where I have limited options in regards to browsers outside of the two I mentioned. Additionally, clearing the cache in my browser actually exacerbated the problem as it removed previously cached versions of the relevant files from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Atwood actually [answered this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32271/stackoverflow-is-not-working-with-ajax/32284#32284) in a similar question on Meta Stack Overflow, in essence, the [Google hosted jQuery library](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) is being blocked by a content filter such as Websense and there isn't a workaround other than getting the content unblocked by an administrator.